# Undoing concat of dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, concatenation

I am doing some machine learning and I need to combine my train and testing set to ensure I treat them the same but I am unable to do this in a simple way and get them back.

```
#combine data sets
df = pd.concat([df_train,df_test],keys=['train','test'])

#This is where I would do stuff but for testing I don't

#reextract original
train=df.loc['train',:]
test=df.loc['test',:]

#check for equality
df_train.equals(train)
```

This returns false and I can't sort out why. df_train and train have the same shape.

I have tried to run

```
df_train = df_train.fillna(0)
df_test = df_test.fillna(0)
```

before to make sure it is not an issue with nulls

EDIT

The function concat changed the type of a column from int to float. Not sure why but now that I know why my assert Statement fails I can safely run the code.

If there is a better method for doing this I would accept an answer with that. For the curios, the reason I need to combine my data sets is so that I can scale and manipulate my data without the possibility of bias to the train or test set.

Comment: Check this: `(df_train.index == train.index).all()` what does it say?

Comment: it's difficult to answer without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you provide small reproducible input data sets and your desired data set? Does `df`have a multi-index?

Comment: COLDSPEED: That is true. 
MaxU: Yea I know. I tried to make one but am unable to reproduce the issue. There are no multi-index in the original dataframes.

At the moment it looks like the issue has something to do with the type handling of concat. When I import I have mixed types  originally. I am going to fix that and see if it solves the problem

Comment: There might be floating point inaccuracies... try `np.allclose(train, df_train)` and see what it prints.

Comment: @Keith, why do you use `keys=['train','test']`?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the df_train set has dtype('int64') and the train set has dtype('float64'). As suggested by COLDSPEED the allclose function returned true. As for why I use this syntax, I need to be able split the sets again after data prep. I am open to other options

Comment: What does `(df_train !=train).sum().sum()` return?

Comment: @Accumulation That returns 0 an will be my new unit test.

Comment: After you do stuff with df, are df_train and df_test not available for some reason?

Comment: I modify df and then just want the rows which originally corresponded to each set. For example a modification could be with sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler or with something to do coding of categorical variables